# Handling java.net.HttpURLConnection to server that does not exist

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

Upon trying to connect to a host/server that does not exist, my program just seems to die.  Stepping through with the debugger lends me nothing, it makes it to `getResponseCode()` and then just stops working.  No exceptions are thrown from what I can tell and the program doesn't return.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
    try {
        //construct a URL and open the connection
        URL url = new URL("http://" + serverHost + ":" + serverPort + urlSuffix);
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        http.setRequestMethod("POST");

        if(http.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect");
        }
        System.out.println("Connected");

        return;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) { //give me something please
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

When connecting to a valid URL, it works fine.

Comment: make sure you read the input stream in any case (especially errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I needed to add `http.setConnectTimeout(10000);` after I opened the connection.  Apparently whatever the default timeout was set as was so long that it appeared to never give a response at all, even when leaving the application open for several minutes.